# Link to iTunes App Storefront

Tags: itunes

I've been trying to figure out how to link to the iTunes Apps storefront rather than a specific app. I know about the Apple Link maker but cannot seem to figure out how to just open iTunes Apps section. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Just found the answer! The link is https://itunes.apple.com/us/genre/ios/id36?mt=8&ls=1&cid=wwa-us-kwg-features-com